# How to copy edge pixels to fill the resized canvas in PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

So I loaded a `480x640` image. I want to place it onto `900x900` canvas, so that original image edge pixels would be propagated to the resulting image borders.

Something like this yet for all sides centring the original image:
[image]
In other words perform something like photoshop Pixel Stretching.

So how one can copy edge pixels to fill the resized canvas in PIL?

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing because the left edge isn't a straight line.  How do you determine where the replication starts?

Comment: Please show your input image, your output image and your latest/greatest code. Thank you.